# clr-datagrid is not a known element error NG8001

Tags: angular, typescript, datagrid, vmware-clarity

Same for clr-column clr-row , even after importing ClarityModule approprietly

```
import { GestionFournisseursComponent } from './gestion-fournisseurs/gestion-fournisseurs.component';
import {ClarityModule} from '@clr/angular';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [GestionFournisseursComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReferentielRoutingModule,
    ClarityModule
  ]
})
export class ReferentielModule { }
```

HTMl:

`<clr-datagrid></clr-datagrid>`

Error:

Error: src/app/main/referentiel/gestion-fournisseurs/gestion-fournisseurs.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'clr-datagrid' is not a known element:

1. If 'clr-datagrid' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'clr-datagrid' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2

```
src/app/main/referentiel/gestion-fournisseurs/gestion-fournisseurs.component.ts:6:16
  6   templateUrl: './gestion-fournisseurs.component.html',
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component GestionFournisseursComponent.

I tried importing the ClarityDatagridModule only, reinstalled clarity , angular , dependencies but always the same error , any help will be appreciated .

Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with **Angular 12.2.17** and **Clarity 12.0.7**
After adding Clarity with the following command:

```
ng add @clr/angular@12.0.7
```

At this point, I had the error.
To fix it, I just used the command:

```
npm install @clr/ui --save
```

I got this command from the Clarity documentation https://clarity.design/documentation/get-started. This solved the error in my case.